# How to add a custom data type to tensorflow?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have my C++ implementation of float24 datatype (stored in 32 bits) with overloaded arithmetic operations. And I want to add this type to tensorflow C++ and Python API for use it in tf graphs running only on CPU.

I did not find a guide how to do it. Where have I to register my type? Will be python code also generated?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Modern CPU's can perform vector instructions on 32 bits floats (multiple floats per instruction), whereas your float24 has to be emulated (multiple instructions per float24). It would be much faster to train in 32 bits and convert the result.

Comment: I certainly know about the hardware acceleration and inefficiency of my implementation. This is the task of my academic research

Comment: Did you find a way for this task? At the moment I am involved to such a problem an I am wondering if you could find a solution for this.

Comment: @sara In short, I did an bfloat16 data type search on the Tensorflow source code and programmed similar code for my data type. There were a lot of macros where a new data type was registered

Comment: @AleksandrKondratyev Please could you share more details? Do you have your code on a public github repo?